# C++ Seconds Minutes Hours when 0

Tags: c++, conditional-statements

I'm a programming beginner learning C++.

I have some code that will give an output in hours mins and seconds.
Like :

```
x hours y minutes z seconds
```

What I want is that when `x, y or z` is equal to `0` to not have that showing up so:
`30hours 0minutes 5seconds` would become: 
`30hours 5seconds`. 
I can do this by using tons of if conditionals but it gets very messed up.
If there's another way please let me know as i really want to learn the right way

Thanks in advance

--EDIT--
This is my actual code

```
if (hours == 0 && mins == 0 && secs != 0) {
    cout <<  secs << "secs " << endl;
}
if (hours == 0 && mins != 0 && secs == 0) {
    cout << mins << "mins " << endl;
}
if (hours != 0 && mins == 0 && secs == 0) {
    cout << hours << "hours " << endl;
}
if (hours == 0 && mins != 0 && secs != 0) {
    cout << mins << "mins " << secs << "secs " << endl;
}
if (hours != 0 && mins == 0 && secs != 0) {
    cout << hours << "hours " << secs << "secs " << endl;
}
if (hours != 0 && mins != 0 && secs == 0) {
    cout << hours << "hours " << mins << "mins " << endl;
}
if (hours != 0 && mins != 0 && secs != 0) {
    cout << hours << "hours " << mins << "mins " << secs << "secs " << endl;
}
```

This works but I dont think thats how actual programmers do it.

Here's the second to hour min secs converter

```
void readabletime(const double a){

hours = a / 3600;
mins = (a/60 - hours * 60);
secs = (a - ((hours * 3600) + (mins * 60)));
```

---UPDATE----
I thought of a simpler way to do it with 3 conditionals

```
if (hours != 0) {
    cout << hours << "hours";
}
if (mins != 0) {
    cout << mins << "mins"
}
if (secs != 0) {
    cout << secs << "secs"
}
```

Comment: Without a specific problem and some code to back it up, this is off-topic. I also don't know why you would need a lot of conditionals.

Comment: _"I can do this by using tons of if conditionals"_ I think two should be actually sufficient.

Comment: Is the time in three actual variables or is it in a tm struct?

Comment: It sounds like it's in three separate variables, the op also said he/she is new so struct may be a stretch at the moment.

Comment: πάντα ῥε - Thats what I mean. I want to know how to do that. I am a beginner

Comment: Just the way to do that. I can read on it myself

Comment: Do you know that you don't have to end a `cout` statement with `endl` so you can later add more text to the same line?

Comment: @indiv yeah i know, but i wanted to here.

Comment: @Afflicted No, I know about struct but I don't see where it would be used here.

Comment: It depends on the situation, more specifically how are you actually handling the conversion. Are you telling the user to input a time in hours minutes and seconds seperatly? Or are you having them enter it in seconds and then using mod? There are quite a few ways to break down your if statements but it would be easier to help if we could see all of your code :)

Comment: They input seconds and i wrote some messy code that turns it into hours,mins and seconds as separate variables. @Afflicted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
if (hours > 0)
    cout << hours << "hours ";

if (minutes > 0)
    cout << minutes << "minutes ";

if (seconds > 0)
    cout << seconds << "seconds ";

cout << endl;
```

That code should do what you want, with only 3 conditionals. If all values are zero, just a new line will be printed.

Comment: In the question, the sample he gave was `x hours y minutes and z seconds` including the word and - even though he didn't know how to code it that seems to be what he is after.  How would you do that considering the and will move around depending on which values are zero?

Comment: Thats exactly what I meant. I was updating the text right when you wrote this.

Comment: @JerryJeremiah It was deduced from his "would become" statement that he didn't need the word "and" in the output. Looks like the deduction was accurate based on the recent edit by OP.